# VIm: copy match with cursor position atom to local variable

Tags: regex, vim

I'm searching for a way to copy match result to local variable in vim script.

The issue is that I want to match text that includes cursor position atom `\%#`, that is, for example: `[A-Za-z:]*\%#[A-Za-z:]\+`, which matches identifiers like `::namespace::ParentClass::SubClass` text under cursor (so `<cword>` does not work for me).

I would like to use this later in a script, but the more I dig the more I start to wonder if that's even possible (or: if I should do it differently, by collecting current line, cursor position and then just extract the identifier under cursor manually).

If that's not possible from within the vim script - what would be the idea behind the `\%#` atom? what is its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- separate the pattern into parts before and after the cursor, get the current line, separate into before / after cursor, and match each with the separated patterns; this uses `getline()`, `strpart()`, and `matchstr()`, and is just like what you've hinted at in your question.
- use `search()` twice from the current position, once to find the end of the match after the cursor, once to find the begin of the match before / on the cursor, then use `getline()` and `strpart()` to extract the matching text:

```
function! GetMatch(pattern)
    let start = searchpos(a:pattern, 'bcnW')[1]
    if start == 0
        return ''
    endif
    let end = searchpos(a:pattern, 'cenW')[1]
    if end == 0
        return ''
    endif
    return strpart(getline('.'), start - 1, end - start + 1)
endfunction
```

Comment: i was afraid that may be the only option. do you have any thoughts on what would be the use of the `\%#` atom, then?

Comment: Well, it's still crucial in the `GetMatch()` function (to avoid to match something further outside). And you can use it in `:substitute`, or `:match` commands. It's not useless!